# Quelle préposition faut-il utiliser avec « cours » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Faut-il dire

> Je suis entré dans ce cours.

ou

> Je suis entré à ce cours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si *Je suis entré dans ce cours* signifie que j'ai ouvert la porte de la classe et ai pris place à un bureau libre, alors c'est la bonne expression.

Si *Je suis entré à ce cours* signifie que je me suis inscrit à un enseignement, alors je préfère dire: *Je me suis inscrit à ce cours*.